# how to connect múltiples servers with same database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I hired 46 VPS and today only one have with database, and another one like to slave(replica).

How i can connect to this two(or more) server for manage the same database?

For example: server #1 is down, so connect to server #2 or #3, #4, #5...

Right now i know it:

```
$connection=Mysqli_connect(...);
```

Maybe exists another method like to:

```
$connection=mysqli_connect_mutiserver(array(...));
```

I think un a loop to check ping and time response, and if some fail, this return the next good connection.

```
For(...){
    if(ping(...) and timing(...)){
        return $serverInfo;
    }
}
```

P.s: i'm sorry, right now i used my smartphone to post it(maybe dont show the code like to prettyprint.

Comment: Have you tried `mysqli_ping($connection)` ?

Comment: Stick a load balancer in front of the database servers, and connect through that load balancer

Comment: @Daan, but ‘mysqli_ping(...)‘ require a link connection. I need check it before to connect.

Comment: @Mark i like you answer. I don't know whats its the best way but i remember learn about HAProxy. Whats do you think about it? Can you tell me another way o service? Thanks

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/loadbalanced_mysql_cluster_debian